# using the cmd execute in .asp and pasing a a varchar to stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp-classic, ado

I am trying to pass a value to a stored procedure using cmd in an asp page     but I keep getting this:

> Type mismatch: 'cint'
>
> /default/current/purchasing.asp, line 512

The Category column is a `varchar`.  I think I have to pass the datatype.
If I am using an `int` column, I just use `int(sField_PO)`

How do I pass a `varchar` datatype?

```vbs
set prmCategory = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
    prmCategory.Name = "@Category"
    prmCategory.Direction = 1
    prmCategory.Type = 3    'adVarChar  
    prmCategory.Value = (sField_CATEGORY)
    cmd.Parameters.append prmCategory
```

Comment: What's on line 512 of purchasing.asp?

Comment: `adVarChar` is `200` not `3`. (Using ADOVBS.INC or the ADO Typelib will allow the use of these enumeration values by name)

Comment: Shorthand; `cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Category", 200, 1, , sField_CATEGORY)`

Comment: LIne 512 is prmCategory.Value = (sField_CATEGORY)

Comment: Here is the code now and following is the response I am getting: set prmCategory = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
 prmCategory.Name = "@Category"
 prmCategory.Direction = 1
 prmCategory.Type = 200 'adVarChar 
 prmCategory.Value = (sField_CATEGORY)
 cmd.Parameters.Append prmCategoryParameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.

/default/current/purchasing.asp, line 513 (which is cmd.Parameters.append line

Answer (score 0):

Already tried this?

```
set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
with objCmd
    .ActiveConnection   = MyConnection
    .CommandType        = 4 'adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText        = "MY STORED PROCEDURE NAME"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Category", 200, 1, 255, sField_CATEGORY)
    .Execute
end with
set objCmd = nothing
```

If you include the type library you can use constants instead numbers

```
<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" UUID="00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4" NAME="ADODB Type Library" --> 
set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
with objCmd
    .ActiveConnection   = MyConnection
    .CommandType        = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText        = "MY STORED PROCEDURE NAME"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Category", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, sField_CATEGORY)
    .Execute
end with
set objCmd = nothing
```

Comment: thanks Silento..but I works as it is if I use an input value, and I have several columns to update....Here is the code..I have to send in several different comments...

Comment: dim cmd 
 dim prmClient 
 set cmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 cmd.ActiveConnection = db
 cmd.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc
 cmd.CommandText = "p_InfoSYNC_Order_Insert"

 set prmClient = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
 prmClient.Name = "@Client"
 prmClient.Direction = 1 'adParamInput
 prmClient.Type = 3 'adInteger
 prmClient.Value = 1
 cmd.Parameters.append prmClient

 set prmstore = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
 prmStore.Name = "@Store"
 prmStore.Direction = 1
 prmStore.Type = 3
 prmstore.Value = cint(sField_STORE)
 cmd.Parameters.append prmStore

Comment: set prmPO = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
prmPO.Name = "@PO"
prmPO.Direction = 1 'adParamInput
prmPO.Type = 20 
prmPO.Value =  cint(sField_PO)
cmd.Parameters.append prmPO
set prmCategory = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
prmCategory.Name = "@Category"
prmCategory.Direction = 1
prmCategory.Type = 3
prmCategory.Value = 2 '(sField_CATEGORY)
cmd.Parameters.append prmCategory
set prmItemCode = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
prmItemCode.Name = "@ItemCode"
prmItemCode.Direction = 1
prmItemCode.Type = 3
prmItemCode.Value = 3 '(sField_ITEMCODE)
cmd.Parameters.append prmItemCode

Comment: set prmDesc = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
 prmDesc.Name = "@Desc"
 prmDesc.Direction = 1
 prmDesc.Type = 3
 prmDesc.Value = 4 '(sField_DESC)
 cmd.Parameters.append prmDesc

 set prmDistributor = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
 prmDistributor.Name = "@Distributor"
 prmDistributor.Direction = 1
 prmDistributor.Type = 3
 prmDistributor.Value = 5 '(sField_DIST)
 cmd.Parameters.append prmDistributor

Comment: [Client] [smallint] NOT NULL ,
 [Store] [int] NOT NULL ,
 [PO] [int] NOT NULL ,
 [Category] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
 [ItemCode] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
 [Desc] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
 [Distributor] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
 [CaseQty] [bigint] NOT NULL ,
 [CasePrice] [float] NOT NULL ,
 [UnitQty] [int] NULL ,
 [UnitPrice] [float] NOT NULL ,
 [DoNotReorder] [int] NULL ,
 [Notes] [varchar] (100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL

Comment: As I said, if I use an actual value, it works fine..but if I use a (sField_<column_name>, i get an invalid field type, even if I use the cint in front of the int column names...except for the @store and@PO...if I try to use the cint(sField_CaseQty)  I get - Type mismatch: 'cint'

Comment: Also, this is in the .asp page....set cmd = nothing
set prmclient = nothing
set prmPO = nothing
set prmstore = nothing
set prmplu = nothing
set prmcaseqty = nothing
set prmunitqty = nothing

Comment: @BradJarrett: Please ([edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32756794/edit) and) put all this in your original question!